# How to assign domain to a docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker

I use Docker-compose to develop the WordPress website together with Mysql and PHPMyAdmin.
Also, use Portainer to monitor them, showing the health icon, and I can access it by typing the IP address 192.168.188.80:3001, and I can curl the page from port 3001.

I try to assign the domain name for the different containers, there will have a couple of WordPress websites and I plan to host them on ports 3001, 3002, 3003...

I enable the conf file in Nginx and the conf file like

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name forktruck.bcsystems.nz;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3001;
  }
}
```

The yml file is here

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  wp-forktruck-data:
networks:
  wp-forktruck-network:

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./wp-forktruck-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress-forktruck
       MYSQL_USER: wp-forktruck
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 3201:3306  
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1
      interval: 300s
      start_period: 5s
      timeout: 10s
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wp-forktruck-network

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: wp-forktruck
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 3101:80
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1
      interval: 300s
      start_period: 5s
      timeout: 10s
    networks:
      - wp-forktruck-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 3001:80
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1
      interval: 300s
      start_period: 5s
      timeout: 10s
    environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp-forktruck
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress-forktruck
    volumes:
      - ./forktruck:/var/www/
    container_name: wp-forktruck
    networks:
      - wp-forktruck-network
```

but something wrong and the domain name got 520 error.

Comment: A domain name would apply to a _host_, not a specific port or process or container.  You'd have to run a reverse proxy that routed based on the HTTP `Host:` header, run it on the default HTTP/TLS port 443, and get DNS name(s) for the host.  This isn't Docker-specific, and isn't really a programming question at all.

Comment: Yes, I know you mean, but could I use one server to host multiple websites ( base on Docker container ) and assign them to the different domain names?

Comment: You could assign multiple domain names to the host's IP address.  You could use an HTTP server that supported host-based virtual servers (core feature of both Apache and Nginx).  You cannot "assign a domain name to a container" as a first-class operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the redirect option in nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name forktruck.bcsystems.nz;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3001;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_redirect http://0.0.0.0:3001 http://forktruck.bcsystems.nz/;
  }
}
```

And should work, good luck

Comment: Thank your answer, but didn't work for me, do I need to change the IP address from 0.0.0.0 to an internal or public IP address?

Comment: First you must validate that the subdomain point to the server. I tested in terminal ubuntu "dig forktruck.bcsystems.nz", and shows 2 ips, what i understand, for working you must say one ip for reference, so that's first step. Then you must validate "subdomain" its working, with the port forktruck.bcsystems.nz:3001 (modify nginx to access to wp with port, http 200 response must you get) , and the last modification is the nginx redirect... If is not working, you can try change 0.0.0.0 with the forktruck.bcsystems.nz... If i was in your pants haha, i  would do that in this order. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Cloudflare? What is your Cloudflare DNS configs. Are you sure that the domain is pointing to public address of 192.168.188.80 (as 192.168.188.80 is private IP address and it's accessible only on your internal network but not the internet).

If you don't know your public IP address, run `curl ipinfo.io` on the 192.168.188.80 server to get your public IP address. And then update your Cloudflare DNS config of domain `forktruck.bcsystems.nz` to that address.

Note: it's easy and worked only if you are using static IP address. If not, please consider https://ngrok.com/ instead of Cloudflare.

Comment: Thank you answer, I have double-checked the public IP address in Cloudflare and it should be fine, I use the same address to host another website for the test purpose, before using docker.